# Query model within model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

```
[
    {
        "_id": "59009087f8ed4e2ecc91fcbe",
        "password": "test",
        "email": "",
        "username": "root",
        "__v": 3,
        "stats": [
            {
                "_id": "590090a0f8ed4e2ecc91fcbf",
                "time": 98,
                "scramble": "U2 F R U' R B' L' U L' B2 R2 B F' U2 R' B2 R2 D R2 U",
                "type": "three",
                "status": 0,
                "date": "2017-04-26T12:20:48.622Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "590090adf8ed4e2ecc91fcc0",
                "time": 120,
                "scramble": "R2 U2 D' U' B D B L' U2 R2 F2 L2 R' F2 U F2 L2 D L2",
                "type": "three",
                "status": 0,
                "date": "2017-04-26T12:21:01.318Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "590090da8f0e120320f36945",
                "time": 191,
                "scramble": "F2 B' L F R B' F B' D' F2 R2 B U' D' F U D B' F' D",
                "type": "four",
                "status": 0,
                "date": "2017-04-26T12:21:46.679Z"
            }
        ],
        "accountDate": "2017-04-26T12:20:23.085Z"
    }
]
```

I have a collection of users. One of the user is shown in the code above. I want to select one user by its id. Then FROM THE SELECTED USER I want objects from the stats array which have type: "three". I have looked for quite some time and havent found a solution. The current method I am using is this:

```
User.findOne({
        _id: id
    }, function (err, user) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            user.stats.forEach(function (time, i, array) {
                if(time.type != req.body.type){
                    array.splice(i, 1);
                }
            });
            res.send(user.stats);
        }

});
```

The problem is that the stats array will get too large and the process will be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find a way to select from the stats array in the query, I'd say at least do not use `splice` to filter out stats of the wrong type. Try using filter, or pushing stats of type 'three' into a new array to see if the performance improves.

https://jsperf.com/splice-vs-filter

Comment: I did that. My TTFB is around 250ms. Is that good? Sometimes it jumpes to 2s.